# basic login using auth component in cakephp2.2

Tags: cakephp-2.2

could you tell how to use auth component in cake2.2 to login by authenticating from the database table.
As my AppController.php is:
`

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');
    var $helpers = array('Form');




}`
```

my UsersController.php is:

```
    class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Auth'); 

    function login() 
    {

    }
    function logout() 
    {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
  }
```

my view as:view\user\login.ctp

```
    <?php
    echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the Auth configurations component and should look something like

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'users'
        ),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The function for the login, which is kinda the same as Ceeram posted it

```
<?php
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Everything that i am saying it's on the oficial documentation  and this tutorial about Auth is really well explained http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html